# Use laptop as a worker node with separate master node

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, cluster-computing

my problem is the same: i have an extra laptop and want use it like a kubernetes worker node, instead having the master node and worker node  in the same machine(like minikube).
the machine with the master node and the laptop with worker node are on the same LAN.
but i have no idea about the technology which i have to use (openshift or something else)
thanks for all

Comment: Welcome, please take a read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure you know how to [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before continuing your trip in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you opt for creating Highly Available Clusters on bare metal, just follow official kubernetes.io's tutorial: [Creating Highly Available Clusters with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/), take option: with stacked control plane nodes.

Comment: Hi Colo, If the answer was useful please upvote/accept it. This helps the community to identify useful answers and rewards whom replied to your post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for this purpose will be kubeadm: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/. You basically doing `kubeadm init` on master, and `kubeadm join` on every worker.

Comment: the idea is have 2 control pane, but how they find out?

Comment: Didn't get your question. Once you did `init` it creates a master and outputs an example command with a token. Then you run it on nodes to join the master.